# Validating an XML file with multiple schematron files

Tags: xml, validation, schematron

I have an XML file to be validated using Schematron.  This file is a long file.  So in order to make the job easier, I made separate Schematron rule files.  Each Schematron file validates different section of the XML file.  If the XML file is successfully validated with all Schematron files, then the XML file is valid.  Otherwise, it is not a valid XML file.

Is there any way to make ONE Schematron file that will call all the other Schematron files?
The ONE is like the root or main that will use other Schematron files to validate the XML file.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Schematron iso:include to include rules from other Schematron (XML) files. A more detailed explanation can be found here: http://www.dpawson.co.uk/schematron/abstract.html

However, your Schematron environment has to support this also. An affordable Schematron validator with ISO Schematron includes support would be [XML ValidatorBuddy](http://www.xml-tools.com/ValidatorBuddy.htm).